# group_concat on sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `sql server management studio 14.0.17825.0` and would like to use `group_concat` function. But I get error when i try to use. The error is `invalid column name group_concat` Is there any other function that I could use? Could you provide a sample code which could achieve what function `group_concat`?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2017+, the function is called [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select string_agg(col, ',') within group (order by col)
```

In earlier versions, you use a trick with XML, that might look like:

```
select stuff( (select ',' + col
               from t
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            )
```

Comment: why do we need `within group (order by col)`? is it possible to use `distinct` such as `select string_agg(distinct (col), ',')`

Comment: i get an error `'string_agg is not a recognized built in function name.`

Comment: @user2543622 . . . I think the question addresses those issues.

Comment: that worked but how do i get the other columns in the data? for example I have two columns `col1, col2` and i would like to get data for `col2` concatnated for each value of 'col1'

Comment: @user2543622 . . . You would have a different question and that should be asked as  *new* question.